# C++ While loop repeatedly called within a single function call

Tags: c++

I am calling a function to deep copy a doubly linked list. I've gone through it with a debugger and everything works perfectly. The error occurs after everything goes well: the first while loop is called AGAIN. I have made sure that it is not a case of the function being called repeatedly or anything else. I am still fairly new to programming so I'm hoping that I'm only missing something simple.

EDIT: For clarity of my issue: when running step-by-step in a debugger, the execution cursor jumps from the start of the second while loop to the start of the first while loop. (line 16 to line 7) upon adding the return at the end, it jumps from the return (line 24) to the first while loop (line 7)

```
void DblLinkedList::DeepCopy(DblLinkedList &source) 
{
    Node *tempCur   = source.current; //temporary holder to reset source's current

    source.current = source.first;

    while(source.current != NULL) // traverse source list and copy each value into empty list
    {
        InsertItem(source.current->data);
        source.current = source.current->succ; // iterate source list
    } 

    source.current = source.first;
    current = first;

    while(source.current != tempCur) //setting the new`enter code here` list's current to the correct node
    {
        source.current = source.current->succ;
        current = current->succ;

        if(source.current == tempCur)
            return; //unnecessary return that doesn't fix anything
    }
return; //unnecessary return that doesn't fix anything
}
```

Comment: Then you must be calling DeepCopy() twice somewhere, no?

Comment: i checked with the debugger and all of this happens within a single call of DeepCopy. I put tabs on the function call and it only hits once

Comment: Please describe what you directly observe. "The loop runs again" — bad. "Message XYZ is printed on the standard output twice" — good. "When running step-by-step in a debugger, the execution cursor jumps from line A to line B" — also good.

Comment: It seems everything OK from the above code! Can you post your whole source code?

Comment: Based on the code you are showing, your assertion does not seem plausible.

Comment: place a breakpoint at `Node *tempCur   = source.current;` and lets see if it gets hit twice

Comment: The code provided doesn't have the behaviour described, so @OldProgrammer is right. Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and in doing so, you might even find the problem by yourself).

Comment: A side note. A list should not have a "current" element. It's bad design.

Comment: remove the last if statement.

Comment: Per your description, something in you first loop is surely calling DeepCopy and you are not aware of it. As others have mentioned, instead of writing a debug report, provide a runnable code.

Comment: Sometimes with sufficient optimization the line orders will not be respected and you will jump around a function - if this was optimized - try it with no optimization

Comment: Of course, the line "    while(source.current != NULL) // traverse source list and copy each value into empty list" will be hit multiple times. This is a loop and this is what loops do: they repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this actually counts as an answer, but I figured out that my function actually works correctly. Following the commentors' advice helped!

The real error occurs when DeepCopy is called by an overloaded "=" operator. When the final line in the overload function `return *this;` runs, it calls DeepCopy() again, which is where the error occurs. I'm not sure how to avoid this error or why `return *this` calls DeepCopy() in the first place

rhs and lhs mean "right/left hand-side" of the operator

(I am very new here, would it be better to post a second question thread regarding this? or just leave it as is)

```
DblLinkedList DblLinkedList::operator=(DblLinkedList &rhs)
{
    if(this != &rhs)//if they aren't the same list
    {
        //delete original lhs list
        this->~DblLinkedList();
        //make lhs a copy of rhs
        DeepCopy(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Your error is returning from `operator=` by value. Return by reference.

Comment: Your another error is calling the destructor explicitly. Don't. Instead, write a function that releases the contents, and call it from here and from the destructor.

Comment: Clarification: `return *this` by value calls the copy constructor, which probably also calls the deep copy. Aside: learn how to display the call stack in your debugger, and always do that if you see anything strange. You would be able to figure all this out just by looking at the call stack.